# Papers on Tensor factorization

Tags: convergence-divergence, tensors, matrix-decomposition, research, tensor-decomposition

I started reading a few papers on Tensors. Right now I am reading a paper by Chi and Kolda called  “[On Tensors, Sparsity, and Nonnegative Factorizations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.2414)”. I passed linear algebra and calculus courses. But I could not understand the proofs in this paper. Could any one suggest how to build the background? are there any online courses or books that could help?

I would appriciate any guidance.

Thanks